# Android XML Issue - images not displaying in AVD

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm fairly new to android but I've managed to figure out how all the layout stuff works with XML. That's all fine.

In the Graphical Layout tab in Eclipse I have a few buttons and a logo which is a .gif image. I have place the .gif image into my XML file as an ImageView within a LinearLayout and it shows up on the Graphical Layout.

But when I run it in the Android Virtual Device (AVD) everything shows up but the image. Anyone know why this is happening? See XML code below...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/natlib"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-8dp"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:text="@string/welsh_libs"
        android:textColor="#79438F"
        android:textSize="22dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="137dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:background="#A4C81C"
        android:text="@string/ask_lib" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="137dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:background="#FF0066"
        android:text="@string/find_book" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="137dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:background="#3F83F1"
        android:text="@string/find_lib" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="137dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:background="#FE0002"
        android:text="@string/register" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="137dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="#FBFC3F"
        android:text="@string/login" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.37"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
        android:src="@drawable/wag_logo"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Which folder did you place the image in? **/res/drawable**?
Also, which folder did you place the layout in? **/res/layout**?

The `/res/` folder and it's subfolders are used in [Localization](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html).

So if you only have it in `/res/drawable-xhdpi/`, it'll only show up on very large devices.

Also, if you modified your layout file at `/res/layout-large/` and didn't modify the one at `/res/layout`, only the large version would get the modifications.

Comment: I placed the image in /res/drawable-mpdi do I need a copy in every screen sized based folder? hdpi, ldpi, etc.?

Comment: Place it in /res/drawable for now. If you place it in /res/drawable/, it will be the default. If you place it in /res/drawable-mpdi/, it will only be for mdpi screen densities.

Comment: Also, keep in mind in the long term, you probably want different sizes of the image depending on how big the screen size/density is.. so in the end, you probably need a different version of the image for each drawable folder hdpi, ldpi, etc.

Comment: Okay thanks very much, sorry if this is obvious stuff. Quite new to android (as in three days into it).

Comment: Nah Localization isn't obvious at first, I launched my first app without proper Localization... :) There's a lot of neat things you can do with it though. Even the /res/values/ can be /res/values-mdpi/ or /res/values-en/ for your english version. Screen sizes, different languages, densities.. it's definitely worth reading up on.

Answer (score 0):

set android:layout_height greater than 0...try this

```
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.37"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
    android:src="@drawable/wag_logo"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```